# recursive succession $a_{n+1}=7a_n-\frac{1}{a_n}, |a_0|>\frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm given this recursive succession:

$a_{n+1}=7a_n-\frac{1}{a_n}, |a_0|>\frac{1}{2}$.

This is what I've done:

$L=7L-\frac{1}{L} \rightarrow L_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt 6}$ and $L_2=-\frac{1}{\sqrt 6}$.

Once I arrived at this point I don't know how to proceed.

my book says that the limit is $+ \infty$ if $a_0 > \frac{1}{2}$ and $- \infty$ if $a_0 < -\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Yo can do this provided that the limit exist. But a priori we don't know. i.e you can't write $L=7L-1/L$.

Comment: The thing is, that you can go to limit only if you proved that limit exists. To prove that limit exists often use monotone convergence theorem

Comment: If $a_0>1/2$ then $1/a_0<2$, and $7a_0-1/a_0>7a_0-2$. Can you continue now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $$a_{n+1}-a_n= 6a_n-\frac{1}{a_n}= \frac{6a_n^2-1}{a_n}$$

- If $a_0>\frac{1}{2}$ then $(a_n)$ is increasing.
- if $a_0<\frac{-1}{2}$ then $(a_n)$ is decreasing.

This means that $(a_n)$ either has a finite limit or diverges to $\pm \infty$ (depending on $a_0$). You have shown that if $(a_n)$ has a limit, it would be $1/\sqrt{6}$ or $-1/\sqrt{6}$ which is impossible in both cases so $a_n\to \infty$ if $a_0>1/2$ and $a_n\to -\infty$ if $a_0<-1/2$.

Comment: could you show more clearly why $(a_n)$ is increasing is $ a_0 > \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @Anne: Sure. Assume that $a_n>1/2$ then $\frac{6a_n^2-1}{a_n}>0$ which means that $a_{n+1}>a_n$ This would mean that $1/2<a_0<a_1<a_2<\dots$.

Comment: why couldn't it be possible that the limit is finite?

Comment: You have proved that if the limit is finite then it is $1/\sqrt{6}$ or $-1/\sqrt{6}$ both of them are smaller than $1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a_n>1/2,$ then $2>\dfrac1{a_n},$ so $-2<-\dfrac1{a_n},$

so $a_{n+1}=7a_n-\dfrac1{a_n}>7a_n-2>3a_n+4a_n-2>3a_n$